# Stop autoscroll when it reaches the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

I have a page that autoscrolls when the use click a button, which works fine but when it reaches the end of the page it won't allow the user to scroll back up. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
$(".playBtn").click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with our code is that it was taking 30 seconds to complete, then *looked* as if it had finished the animation, but really hadn't, and was still completing its animation while you were trying to scroll up - hence why you couldn't scroll up.

The second parameter in your animate function tells the animation how long to take to complete - in milliseconds. Also the *'html'* part of your *'html, body'* wasn't doing anything, hence I've removed it, here's the new code:

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('body').height() }, 1500);
```

And here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpaEv/